# What exactly returns canvas.coords()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got some problems (again !) : according to [this documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf) should

```
temporary = cv.create_text(a,b, text = "ip example", anchor = E)
x,y = cv.coords(temporary)
print(coords)
```

return a tuple `(x1,y1,x2,y2)`
Sadly I only get two coordinates : (ex : `(347.08203932499373, 320.5342302750968)`).

What went wrong ?

EDIT :

1) More precisely, this point is in the documentation p.23, .coords § @DeepSpace

2) I understood this point, but I absolutely need the top-left AND bottom right apex coordinate. If cv.coords() doesn't return these values, how could I find them ? @RonNorris

Comment: Can you please be more specific than "this documentation"? "this documentation" is 168 pages.

Comment: The document says about coordinates `The number of coordinates depends on the type of object. In most cases it will be a 4-tuple (x1
, y1
, x2
, y2
) describing the bounding box of the object`. The rule of thumb is that if it takes two coordinates to define the object (text in your case), then that is the number of coordinates the command will return. For example, rectangles return four coordinates, polygons return the coordinates with which they were created, etc.

Comment: I edited my post ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing went wrong. A text item has only two coordinates.

It sounds like you are looking for the coordinates of the *bounding box*  rather than the coordinates of the item. The bounding box is the smallest rectangle that completely surrounds your item. You can get the coordinates of the bounding box with the `bbox` method:

```
x0, y0, x1, y1 = cv.bbox(temporary)
```

The official documentation for the bbox command says this:

> Returns a list with four elements giving an approximate bounding box for all the items named by the tagOrId arguments. The list has the form “x1 y1 x2 y2” such that the drawn areas of all the named elements are within the region bounded by x1 on the left, x2 on the right, y1 on the top, and y2 on the bottom. The return value may overestimate the actual bounding box by a few pixels. If no items match any of the tagOrId arguments or if the matching items have empty bounding boxes (i.e. they have nothing to display) then an empty string is returned.

Comment: yes, you are right. I removed the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you, yourself unpack the first two elements of the tuple by assigning `x,y = cv.coords()`

Either you just assign `x = cv.coords(...)` and use `x[0],..x[3]` to access the values.

or unpack it like `x1, x2, y1, y2 = cv.coords(...)`